# How to make a script on vi that counts lines of .txt files?

Tags: linux, bash

How to make a script that counts the lines of the .txt files in my work directory.For Every file it must output a file with form "10 file 4.text" that 10 is the number of lines for the 4th file.
all the lines must be saved in an "OUTPUT" file the contents of this file must be classified in descending line order.
for example:

```
100 file3.txt
69 file4.txt
45 file1.txt
32 file2.txt
...
```

The script must print an "OUTPUT" file at the end.

Here is the script i have tried:

```
#! /bin/bash

while [ ! -s input.txt ]
do
echo waiting...

sleep 5
for f in *.txt
do
echo sorting file $f
cat $f | sort > $f.sorted

lines=`wc -l $*.txt`
echo "the file $*.txt has $lines lines
echo sorted file has been output to $f.sorted
done
```

Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
wc -l *.text | sort -r > OUTPUT
```